# Embed Flow and Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

I have created a lightning flow and embeded it with the Lightning component. I am getting an error while invoking the flow from the lightning component.

**Lightning Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" controller="AB_AmendOppCntrl">
        <aura:attribute name="objOpportunity" type="Opportunity"/>
        <aura:attribute name="objOppId" type="Id"/>
        <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" access="global"/>
        <!--force:recordData aura:id="opportunityRecord" recordId="{!v.recordId}" fields="AB_Select_the_Amendment"
                          targetRecord="{!v.objOpportunity}" /-->
        <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
        <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData"/>
    </aura:component>
```

**Controller.js**

```
({
    init : function (component) {
        var action = component.get("c.fetchRecord");
        action.setParams({
            'recId': component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();
                console.log('storeResponse===>',storeResponse);
                component.set("v.recordId",storeResponse.id);
                // Find the component whose aura:id is "flowData"
                if(storeResponse.StageName == "Closed Won"){
                    var flow = component.find("flowData");
                    var inputVariables = [
                        {
                            name : "recordId",
                            type : "SObject",
                            value : { 
                                "Id" : component.get("v.recordId"),
                            }
                            //value : component.get("v.recordId")
                        }
                    ];
                    console.log('inputVariables=====>',inputVariables);
                    // In that component, start your flow. Reference the flow's Unique Name.
                    flow.startFlow("AB_Select_the_Amendment", inputVariables );


                }else{
                    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                    toastEvent.setParams({
                        "title":"Error",
                        "message":"Opportunity is not in closed won stage."
                        //"type":"error"
                    });
                    toastEvent.fire()
                }
            }

        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

})
```

In flow I have created the variable called "recordId" as "text" data type and as a input variable.

Please see the following image of the recordId
[image]

So my question is like what should be the data type of the recordId in controller.js. I have tried with the String but i am getting an error as

> We can't launch this flow because of a variable error. Send this error message to your admin. The value {} is being provided for variable recordId but isn't compatible with the variable's data type (String). Check the places where you implemented the flow ‒ such as through a Lightning page or a custom button ‒ and make sure that all provided values are compatible with the variables' data types.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please 
Replace

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" access="global"/>
```

With

```
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" access="global"/>
```